# How to solve [web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor]

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, truffle

I`m getting this error.

```
truffle(development)> const mycontract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
```

> Thrown:
> TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor

This happens when I set `mycontract` on console.
Web3 version is `1.0.0

Could you give me any advise, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Truffle 5 and you already run `truffle deploy` command, you can simply run the following in your `truffle console` terminal:

```
const mycontract = await YourContract.deployed()

// or

const mycontract = await YourContract.at("0x_your_contract_address")
```